# CakePHP 3 clear selected input value from controller after submit

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP 3, how can I clear only one selected input value from controller after submit? I do not want to clear all input values, just of the one input.

Comment: try ```$data = $this->getRequest()->getData();``` then ```unset($data['fieldname'])``` or ```$this->getRequest()->withData('fieldname', null)```.

Comment: Thank you, please write it as an answer, I will mark "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your controller:**

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getData();
unset($data['fieldname']); // unset / remove field from array
```

**or set null value for that field**

```
$this->getRequest()->withData('fieldname', null);
```